# VBA Workbook_BeforeClose still prompts the Save window after setting Cancel to true. Clicking Save on that menu then closes the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT:

The issue is caused by a custom security addon that my company uses.  Nothing I can do about it and is a very select problem, so I'm deleting the question so I don't confuse anyone who finds this in the future.

Comment: It happens when you select Yes on the messagebox?

Comment: When I select No on my custom messagebox, the sub does what it's supposed to.  After completion, it then pops up the default "Do you want to save changes" box.  Clicking Save on THAT one then closes the workbook without firing the beforeclose event.  I thought that setting "Activeworkbook.saved = true" would suppress the 2nd message box, but it doesn't.

Comment: Not the answer you were hoping to find, but glad you were able to identify the root cause. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If ValidateData = True Then
        Call SendAndSave
    Else
        Select Case MsgBox("There are some invalid entries on the worksheet (values can only be between 0 and 5) so the changes were NOT " & _
            "sent to the server.  Do you still want to close the tool?", vbYesNo, "Warning")
        Case vbYes
            ThisWorkbook.Saved = True '/ won't ask the user to save
            ' but will still close.
        Case vbNo
            ThisWorkbook.Saved = True ''/ won't ask the user to save
            Cancel = True '/ Won't Close
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's still showing the second dialogue box.

Comment: This seems to be working for me using either of `ThisWorkbook` or `Me` keyword.

Comment: Yeah for me too. VBA Noob , do you have any code on the other events such as BeforeSave?

Comment: The only other workbook level sub I have is 

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call PullData
End Sub

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with a company-specific addon.  Even this still prompts the save box which will exit the workbook:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

     Cancel = true

end sub

Comment: The `Cancel` parameter in `Workbook_BeforeClose` event doesn't suppress the "Save" dialog. It provides a means by which you can abort the `Close` operation. To suppress the "Save" dialog, you need to do that using the workbook's `.Saved` property per @cyboashu answer. This tricks Excel in to treating the workbook as though it is saved, even if it is not.

Comment: I've tried Me.Saved=True, ThisWorkbook.Saved=True and ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True.  None of those are preventing the save dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to block before_save, telling him "i come from before_close" just by adding a module global boolean.
If this boolean is true in before_save then cancel=true.

```
option explicit
Private BlockNormalSave as boolean

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(Cancel As Boolean)
if BlockNormalSave then Cancel=true
end sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
BlockNormalSave=true
application.displayalerts=false 'not sure if prevents save window
thisworkbook.saved=true
'thisworkbook.close save:=false 'not sure either
end sub
```