# workbook does not save

Tags: excel, vba

Although if I have the following code

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   MsgBox "Hello"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False       
   If Not ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

the workbook still ask to be saved why?

The "Hello" is displayed after the excel pop-up for saving the workbook

The expected behaviour is to avoid the "Do you want to save the workbook" pop-up on closing it (see picture below)

[image]

**UPDATE**
all lines of code in `Workbook_BeforeClose` are fired but although the  `ActiveWorkbook.Save` is fired, the pop-up above still show up

**UPDATE 2**
Finally I figured it out  or at least this solution worked for me
after reading [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247434/vba-workbook-beforeclose-still-prompts-the-save-window-after-setting-cancel-to-t/41272059)  I then just out of curiosity disabled the "Analysis ToolPack" add-in and bum.. all work fine now.

Any comments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426907/difference-between-thisworkbook-name-and-activeworkbook-name-in-vba

Comment: You can disable alerts although you are not giving a lot of info. What is the expected behavior? Telling us what is wrong is only half the picture.

Comment: The expected behaviour is to avoid the "Do you want to save the workbook" pop-up on closing it

Comment: You should be using `Me` or `ThisWorkbook` in place of `ActiveWorkbook`.  `ActiveWorkbook` could be some other workbook entirely.

Comment: @Tim WIlliams I tried that too, same result

Comment: The Help for this event says "If the workbook has been changed, this event occurs before the user is asked to save changes."  So it's odd that you're seeing the pop-up *before* the Hello...

Comment: excatly!!! I am getting totally nut. I am on this since yesterday afetroon and is a nonsense

Comment: the problem is not if I am using Me or ThisWorkBook , the problem is that the save prompt fire up before any line of code is hit in the Before_Close event; seems like thisworkbook is not the workbook of this application :-)

Comment: check my update 2 for the solution and please do comment on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out or at least this solution worked for me after reading [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247434/vba-workbook-beforeclose-still-prompts-the-save-window-after-setting-cancel-to-t/41272059) I then just out of curiosity disabled the "Analysis ToolPack" add-in and bum.. all work fine now.